# Как записать полученные числа в текстовый файл? на js

Tags: node.js

```
let n = 21;
let fibonacci = [0, 1];
for (let i = 2; fibonacci[i - 1] < n; i++) {
    fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2];
}
console.log(fibonacci);
```

Comment: [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let n = 21;
let fibonacci = [0, 1];
for (let i = 2; fibonacci[i - 1] < n; i++) {
    fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2];
}
const content = fibonacci.join(', ');

const myFileName = 'fibonacci.txt';
const pathToFile = path.join(process.cwd(), myFileName);
fs.writeFileSync(pathToFile, content);
```

Читайте документацию, там ответы на все ваши вопросы.
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/